# Libgdx center Scaled Textbutton in HorizontalGroup

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Putting TextBttons into a HorizontalGroup, then scaling them results in a distorted view, even with centered alignment.

```java
add_button = new TextButton("+",textButtonStyle);
add_button.setTransform(true);
add_button.setScale(0.7f);
add_button.setDebug(true);
remove_button = new TextButton("-",textButtonStyle);
remove_button.setTransform(true);
remove_button.setScale(0.7f);
remove_button.setDebug(true);

HorizontalGroup brush_op_group = new HorizontalGroup();
brush_op_group.addActor(remove_button);
brush_op_group.addActor(add_button);
brush_op_group.setDebug(true);
```

which results in the below image:

[image]

It seems like the buttons positions are calculated based on their unscaled sizes. 
How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose I ended up using tables:

```java
add_button = new TextButton("+",textButtonStyle);
add_button.setTransform(true);
add_button.setOrigin(Align.left | Align.top);
add_button.setScale(0.8f);
remove_button = new TextButton("-",textButtonStyle);
remove_button.setTransform(true);
remove_button.setOrigin(Align.right | Align.top);
remove_button.setScale(0.8f);

HorizontalGroup file_op_group = new HorizontalGroup();
Table brush_op_group = new Table().center();
brush_op_group.add(remove_button).right();
brush_op_group.add(add_button).left();
brush_op_group.setDebug(true);
```

Works like a charm!

[image]